# Is it normal that importing vuetify.min.css does nothing? (with Vue 3 and Vite)

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I'm working on a **Vue 3** project and I'm using **Vuetify**.
I want to import `vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css` but when I add it to my main.js, nothing changes.
I thought this line included several parameters for my components as in my **Vue 2** project.

The difference with my new project is that I'm using vite and not webpack, so I don't know if I need to do anything to make my import work.

This is my `main.js` :

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
// I can remove ths line and nothing will change...
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' 
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
import '@scss/app.scss'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'


import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import { aliases, fa } from 'vuetify/iconsets/fa'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'light',
    themes: {
      light: {
        dark: false,
        colors: {
          primary: '#B5E0D6',
          secondary: '#2C3E4E',
          secondarydark: '#1A242C',
          lightgrey: '#E3E4E6',
          mediumgrey: '#9E9E9E',
          darkgrey: '#5B5B5C',
          accent: '#2C3E4E',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'fa',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      fa,
    },
  },
})
app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

and this is my `vite.config.js` :

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8081,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vuetify(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@src': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@comp': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/components', import.meta.url)),
      '@page': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/pages', import.meta.url)),
      '@lang': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/languages', import.meta.url)),
      '@scss': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/scss', import.meta.url)),
      '@static': fileURLToPath(new URL('./static', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@import "@scss/variables.scss";',
      },
    }
  }
})
```

I think I need to change some parameters in my `vite.config.js` file but I don't know what.

I want to use it because in my vue 2 project, i can do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUGvW.png) thank to that.
Now with vue 3 i don't have my `background-color="primary"` if i select an option

Comment: What would be the purpose of importing that file when `import 'vuetify/styles'` imports the global vuetify styling already?  The [installation instructions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/) cover everything and does not mention needing to import any `vuetify.min.css` file (outside of CDN installation)... What is the actual problem or issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: For example, in my **vue 2** project, we import `vuetify.min.css` and `vuetify/styles` and when we use `<v-btn :disabled="var">` and my button is disabled, it has a special background color. With **vue 3**, I use the same imports but I don't have this background color. I don't think it's because **vuetify** has changed its style. Also, I can't find this `vuetify.min.css` class in the browser development tools with **vue 3**.

Comment: the difference is the Vuetify 2 installation instructions explicitely instruct you to import `vuetify.min.css`.  That's not a thing anymore in Vuetify 3.  Don't import it.  Follow the Vuetify 3 instructions. Don't unnecessarily combine different instructions from different versions.

Comment: I understand better, thank you. However, I have another question. When I select an option in a `<v-select>`, I want the option to have a `<background-color="primary">`. As I showed in my post that I just edited